# MPAndroidChart: How to add legend (text explaining colors used) for BarChart?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart library to draw a BarChart, I am using 3 three colors to draw bars, based on bar value.

I want to show text that explains what each color is (i.e., a legend) as in the below image.

[image: a bar chart with 3 colors and a legend on the side labelling the green color "company A", the blue color "company B" etc.]

In the example image, the text I want is the one that says "Company A", "Company B", "Company C".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setCustom()` for this.

```
Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
l.setCustom(colorArray, labelArray);


 /**
 * Sets a custom legend's labels and colors arrays. The colors count should
 * match the labels count. * Each color is for the form drawn at the same
 * index. * A null label will start a group. * A ColorTemplate.COLOR_SKIP
 * color will avoid drawing a form This will disable the feature that
 * automatically calculates the legend labels and colors from the datasets.
 * Call resetCustom() to re-enable automatic calculation (and then
 * notifyDataSetChanged() is needed to auto-calculate the legend again)
 */
```

Comment: setCustom() method ask for an array of LegendEntry, not intArray nor String array neither